# Multiple sql queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a php statement which inputs data into two different tables using various sql queries. The first query works fine but once I get past the

```
if (isset($origin, $destination));
```

point, none of the statements work although the script redirects at the bottom as it would do as if it was complete.

Any help on what is going wrong would be appreciated.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO journey_boards (headline, text, tag, origin, destination, userid)
VALUES
('$_POST[posttitle]', '$_POST[posttext]', '$_POST[tag]', '$_POST[origin]',    '$_POST[destination]', '$_SESSION[id]')";

$origin = $_POST[origin];
$destination = $_POST[destination];

if (isset($origin, $destination)) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM journey_ranking WHERE origin = $origin AND     destination = $destination");
}
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($count = 1) {
    $sql2 = "UPDATE journey_ranking SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE origin = $origin AND destination = $destination";
} else {
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO journey_ranking (origin, destination, rank)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[origin]', '$_POST[destination]', 1)";
    }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}



header('location: journeys.php');

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: 1. `mysqli_query`, `mysql_num_rows` - mixing API is bad. 2. `if ($count = 1)` should be `== 1`

Comment: There are at least half a dozen issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

also, cahnge

```
if (isset($origin, $destination)) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM journey_ranking WHERE origin = $origin AND     destination = $destination");
}
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

to

```
if (isset($origin, $destination)) {
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM journey_ranking WHERE origin = $origin AND     destination = $destination");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
} else $count = 0;
```

AND

```
if ($count = 1) {
```

should be

```
if ($count == 1) {
```